# Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://localhost:8000/" DynamoDB with Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to follow the tutorial within the documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.01.html

as such:

```
def create_movie_table(dynamodb=None):
    if not dynamodb:
        dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb',
                                  aws_access_key_id="anything",
                                  aws_secret_access_key="anything",
                                  region_name = 'us-east-2',
                                  endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000")

    table = dynamodb.create_table(
        TableName='DailyMovers',
        KeySchema=[
            {
                'AttributeName': 'date',
                'KeyType': 'HASH'  # Partition key
            },
            {
                'AttributeName': 'type',
                'KeyType': 'RANGE'  # Sort key
            }
        ],
        AttributeDefinitions=[
            {
                'AttributeName': 'date',
                'AttributeType': 'S'
            },
            {
                'AttributeName': 'type',
                'AttributeType': 'S'
            },

        ],
        ProvisionedThroughput={
            'ReadCapacityUnits': 5,
            'WriteCapacityUnits': 5
        }
    )
    return table


if __name__ == '__main__':

    create_movie_table()
```

However, I keep running into the localhost:8000 connection error.
I am installed boto3 properly.
I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: What is `localhost:8000`?

Comment: Did you install a DynamoDB server on your local computer, as that link says to do?

Comment: @JohnGordon Ah, I will give that a try. I thought I read that if I download AWS-cli it comes included.

Comment: No, it's a Java app that needs to run separately.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thank you got it working. Do you want to include it as answer? I can accept it. I think it may be helpful to other beginners such as myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of DynamoDB that runs from `localhost` for testing is a separate download from Amazon which requires Java to run.  I don't believe it's part of any other package including AWS-cli.  You can find instructions for it at [Setting Up DynamoDB Local (Downloadable Version)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html).